# Javascript: Loading many images into DOM from a custom API without base64-dataURLs

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

Contexxt: I'm currently working on a web-app built using Angular with an API written in Silex.

I've got the following situation:

- An Angular-page with up to hundreds of clickable thumbnails. On click, a lightbox-plugin opens the full-size image
- An API requiring a custom token-header to load each picture

Very well, I thought, and I made the API so it returned images as base64-encoded. Easy enough. Setting this base64-encoded data as image sources is even simpler: `src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + response;`. This is done using an `ngSrc` making it sort of asynchronous. The lightbox uses an anchor-tag's `href` to load the image from (I use Colorbox for this), so per photo I have two rather large base64-dataURLs.

This however causes serious problems. Not immediately with only 1 picture, but as soon as the number of pictures starts to rise. The browser tab starts requiring more and more memory as the base64-URLs remain in the DOM.

I've created a temporary workaround for this by creating a custom Silex controller which does not read its token from the headers but from the query-string instead. This allows me to set the image source to something like: `src = "http://api/img/1?token=" + token;`. Gone is the problem of data-URLs and their memory hunger.

However, in the future the API will most likely start to require HTTP basic auth for fetching images. And the basic auth credentials cannot be passed through the query string. They require headers for functioning. So my workaround will no longer work. Thus, it is a true temporary workaround.

I'm not completely sure how to fix this problem though. Images need to be loaded through an Ajax-call to be able to add the custom headers. The whole thing must be asynchronous so loading is as fast as possible. After an image is loaded it should not take up memory, or at least not much to keep the page performant no matter how many images are being shown.

I've been looking in to loading the base64-based image onto a `canvas`-element. Something like this:

```
$scope.loadThumbnails = function() {
  $scope.photos.forEach(function($photo){
    $photo.canvas_th = document.querySelector('canvas#' + $photo.id + '_th');

    var request = $http({                                                                               
      method: "GET",                              
      url: [URL]                                     
    });                                                                                                 

    var fetchThumbnailSuccess = function(response) {                                                    
      console.debug("Fetched thumbnail with id " + $photo.id);

      // Get drawing context
      var ctx = $photo.canvas_th.getContext("2d");

      // Create image with onload drawing to context
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      }

      // Add data to image object, triggering the onload function which in turn draws the image to the context
      img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response;
    }                                                                                                   
    request.success(fetchThumbnailSuccess);                                                             

    var fetchThumbnailFailure = function(response) {                                                    
      console.error("Failed fetching thumbnail with id " + $photo.id);                                
      console.debug(response);                                                                        
    }                                                                                                   
    request.error(fetchThumbnailFailure);                                                               
  });                                                                                                     
}
```

I'm however not sure if this will be and remain more performant. I am however sure someone else must have coped with a situation like this before. Am I overlooking something? Doing something completely wrong? I'd love to get some help with this as I'm currently stuck with my not-so-fancy workaround... Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas uses as much memory to display an image as an img element does so using canvas will not help your memory issues.

You're stuck with increasing memory requirements as long since you're accumulating encoded urls to store your image data.

Given the limitations of your current light-box, maybe "rolling your own" would give you better performance.

How about just serving up thumnails for your initial display and then change a single full-sized img element's `.src` property to the selected thumbnail's url.

That way you're only taking up memory for the thumbnail display plus a single full-sized image. Have the browser cache the full-sized image so if your user re-looks at a previous full-sized image it will be quickly fetched from the cache rather than re-downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've Googled a bit more and found that it is not completely uncommon to secure access to static resources like I've currently implemented (adding the token to query-params instead of headers). I think I'll have to drop the wish to secure everything a bit more using HTTP basic auth and just keep my current workaround as it is functioning flawlessly and allows the browser to work its magic with caching everything. Something like dynamic loading on scroll will then further improve performance.